# echo to stdout if a sub-function succeeds, suppress stderr if it fails

Tags: bash

Inside of a bash script, I want to define a function to do the following:

1. invoke a sub-program (/usr/sbin/i2sget)
2. if the sub-program succeeds, echo what it printed to stdout
3. if the sub-program fails, suppress stderr and print "SUPPRESSED" on stdout

Here's what I have that doesn't quite work.  (Note: i2sget returns a '0' on success and '2' on a read error):

```
read_i2s_register () {
    local RESULT=`/usr/bin/i2sget -y 1 0x55 0x08`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]: then
        echo ${RESULT}
    else
        echo "SUPPRESSED"
    fi
}
```

When `/usr/bini2sget` succeeds, the above function properly echoes its stdout (captured in ${RESULT}.

But when it fails, it prints "Error: Read failed" (presumably on stderr) and it doesn't print SUPPRESSED on stdout.

What's the right way to accomplish the desired behavior?

Comment: Do you want stderr to print as normal in the success case or can it always be thrown away?

Comment: I need i2get to print results on success.

Comment: "print results" meaning all of its output or just the stdout portion? The solution changes slightly depending on which one you want. `2>/dev/null` throws stderr away entirely, `2>&1` captures stderr together with stdout.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Shellcheck finds the problem.

Comment: If it wasn't for your comment, I wouldn't have known about Shellcheck!  Don't close just yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit code check won't work when you add `local` because that has its own exit status that masks whatever the command exited with. To address this, you have to separate the two pieces:

```
local RESULT
# change 2>/dev/null to 2>&1 if you want
# stderr captured in the RESULT
RESULT=$( /usr/bin/i2sget -y 1 0x55 0x08 2>/dev/null ) 
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
  echo "$RESULT"
else
  echo SUPPRESSED
fi
```

Or a little more succinctly to [avoid an antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern):

```
local RESULT
# change 2>/dev/null to 2>&1 if you want
# stderr captured in the RESULT
if RESULT=$( /usr/bin/i2sget -y 1 0x55 0x08 2>/dev/null ) ; then
  echo "$RESULT"
else
  echo SUPPRESSED
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exit code in the `if` directly. Placing an assignment in the statement let us use the output, or print something else to stderr oterwise:

```bash
if tmp=$(/usr/bin/i2sget -y 1 0x55 0x08 2>&1); then
    echo "Do something with '$tmp'"
else
    echo "SUPPRESSED" >&2
fi
```

---

How I tested this local:

```
➜  ~
➜  ~ function test_ok { echo 'foobar'; return 0; }
➜  ~ function test_nok { echo 'nope'; return 1; }
➜  ~
➜  ~ if tmp=$(test_ok); then echo "Do something with $tmp"; else; echo "SUPPRESSED" >&2; fi
Do somthing with 'foobar'
➜  ~
➜  ~ if tmp=$(test_nok); then echo "Do something with $tmp"; else; echo "SUPPRESSED" >&2; fi
SUPPRESSED
➜  ~
➜  ~
```